# How to detect if user has reached almost the end of the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I fire an event when the user has reached the bottom of the page using this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {       
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

How can this be modified to fire the event when the user reached almost the end of the page, let's say 300px left?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angularjs:
After struggling with it for a long time- stumbled across the library: http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html.

Based on your use-case, you could do something like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div infinite-scroll="addMoreItems()">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">Item number {{$index}}: {{$item}}</div>
</div>
```

As it allows you to attach this to any div- you could almost do anything in the function you want to.